# Magento 2 country name not showing in Billing/shipping address at checkout.

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

I installed fresh Magento 2.1.8.I didn't change anything.
When I am trying to place an order, I noticed country field is empty in billing as well shipping section.

[image: Checkout page - payment method step]

I don't think that I am doing anything wrong.so I think it's magento's  bug.

**Is there anyone else see the same or I forgot something ?**
And **If this bug please give me some smart(without mess up core) solution.**

Thanks.

Comment: I have this same problem. I'll check the Github pages for more intel on this one.

Comment: I filed an issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10886

Comment: Thanks Giel For that info.but many Magento developer I meet claims they can't see this bug. So can you tell me how you install Magento 2.1.8? setup from Command line/run setup in a browser or anything else.

Comment: Just using the browser setup, and in my configuration I only allow 1 country. Also my top destinations was set to 1 country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated this issue and I found in my case that this issue was caused by disabling the `full_page` cache on my local installation (see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10886).

Could you confirm that this is the issue for you as well? If so, this could be considered a bug.

Comment: You are right But I can't enable cache during development so I am going to just ignore it. :(

Comment: I am using Magento 2.4.4 EE version, the full_page cache is in enabled stage, but still the country is not showing on checkout page shipping address section.
Note : After refresh 2 to 3 times, then the country will appeared.