# Magento 2 country not showing on checkout shipping address

Tags: checkout, shipping-address

Hello guys I am working with the magento2, I am facing some issue on my checkout page shipping address section - Country is not showing for the existing address & for the newly created address.

In some of the question it's for the disabled the full_page cache, But in my case the full_page is enabled in my local, but still the country is not showing.

[Magento 2 country name not showing in Billing/shipping address at checkout.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192723/magento-2-country-name-not-showing-in-billing-shipping-address-at-checkout)

[image]

Magento Version 2.4.4

Note : If I refresh the page 2 to 3 times, then the country is appeared.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe someone accidentally removed the country from the shipping address template: `<your theme dir>Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html`

You also can debug JS files related to `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js` (I mean JS files that extend/override `list.js` file).

Comment: I can able to add an address with country

Comment: You are able to add an address with a country does not mean the address template does not has a problem. I've updated my answer, please check.